# kafka command error: Could not find or load main class >-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using confluent-kafka platform. I want to use the commandline tool to list all topics. It shows the error. Under the `./bin` folder:

```
$ ./kafka-topics --list --zookeeper mykafkaaddress:port
Error: Could not find or load main class >-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

I already have the $JAVA_HOME set:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

Comment: What version of confluent platform are you using, and on which environment?

Comment: Also, did you change the script (kafka-topics or kafka-run-class) to add preferIPv4Stack? In this case, I think you added it wrongly. Please post any changes you did to your scripts.

Also, you should use zookeeper (by default with 2181 port), not broker, for kafka-topics. Note this will probably change on future release, kafka team is trying to make client less and less dependent on zookeeper

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere within `kafka-topics` or `kafka-run-class` scripts, you have inserted `>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

For example, you might have done `export KAFKA_OPTS=">-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` or some other export getting added to the internal java command

Starting a new terminal session, inspecting your environment variables, or fixing the script are some solutions to the issue.